# Wrap Object.entries(myObject) output inside html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to output the key-value pairs of a large object on the web page. I was relieved to find that Object.entries() can do just that. But I would need some control over the formatting so I would like to wrap the keys inside a span tag with a a special class and the values with a span tag with a special class.

Is there any easy way of wrapping the output of Object.entries with html tags?

This is the code I used for writing the object on the page:

```
$('.mycontainer').html(Object.entries(myObject));
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype). A `.map` seems to be what you’re looking for.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl I have succesfully written the object to the page with with $('.mycontainer').html(Object.entries(myObject));

Comment: So `Object.entries()` returns an array. Loop over that array and create elements for each key and value instead

Comment: @AndyBay, did any of the answers suit your needs? Can you give feed-back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use jQuery,  I would use `append` and `text` methods like this:

```js
let obj = {
  name: "Helen",
  age: 26,
  gender: "female"
};

$(".container").empty().append(
    $("<table>").append(
        Object.entries(obj).map(pair =>
            $("<tr>").append(
                pair.map(item => $("<td>").text(item))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

```css
.container td:first-child {
    background: silver;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
}

.container td:last-child {
    background: lightyellow;
}

.container td {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I'm having a bit trouble understanding this answer. What does the pair => part do? Is "pair" just a variable name or something special?

Comment: `pair` is just a name I chose for an array with two values: a key and a corresponding value (see the documentation of  [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)). `.map` is called on this pair, so to apply the same logic to the key and the value in that pair. The logic is to create a `td` element with as text that key or value and to return that created element. `.map` will thus return a pair of elements for a key/value pair. This pair of elements is then passed to the `append` call... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this seems to be the easiest way:

```
Object.entries(myObject).forEach(([key, value]) 
=> $('.myContainer').append((
`<span class="k">${key}</span>: <span class="v">${value}</span>`
)));
```

Comment: Use `append()` instead. Using `html()` will wipe out prior iterations leaving only the last one

Comment: Looks like it’s going to replace `.myContainer`’s contents multiple times. Are you sure you don’t simply want to use a `.map` and `.join` before doing `.html`? `.append` updates the DOM several times which is costly in terms of performance.

Comment: I updated the answer to use append() instead of html(). @SebastianSimon I'm not sure if I know how to do what you suggest, but if you make an answer and it's an easier method than my answer, I will happily accept it.

Comment: The downside here is that if `key` or `value` contain HTML-like content, it can mix up the final HTML. It is advisable to use methods that escape `<` and `&` characters, so they don't harm the final HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.entries(myObject)` returns the **array**.

So you can't do like `$('.mycontainer').html(Object.entries(myObject));`
Here you can't direclty assign the array to the html.

The better solution is that you can iterate throw elements and print to HTML.
**Example:**

```
Object.entries(myObject).forEach(([key, value]) {
     $(".myContainer").append(
       `<div>
         <span>${key}</span>: <span>${value}</span>
       </div><br/>`
     );
});
```

Comment: Missing some back ticks for the template literal